Need Help with Adobe Marketplace
I'm currently exploring the Adobe Marketplace and I have a few questions. I hope someone here can help me out.
How do I list my products on the Adobe Marketplace? I'm a developer and I've created some assets that I think would be useful for other Adobe users. What's the process for getting them listed?
Are there any specific requirements or guidelines for submissions? I want to make sure that my products meet all the necessary criteria before submitting them.
How does the payment process work for sellers on the Adobe Marketplace? I'm curious about the payment structure and how royalties are calculated.
Has anyone here had experience selling on the Adobe Marketplace? I'd love to hear about your experiences and any tips you might have for success.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
